# Slack Custom per Channel Slack Notification Sounds?

Tags: notifications, slack

I know how to mute notifications on a per-channel basis, and how to change what triggers notifications on a per-channel basis in Slack. But best I can tell, there is no way to set a unique notification sound on a per-channel basis. Is there a way to get a unique notification sound for a particular slack channel.

Why? I want some channels to grab my attention more than others. Particularly, channels that alerts drop into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Slack **does not** provide an option to customize notification sound on **per channel** basis.

As you have rightly mentioned, in channels and DMs with three or more people, you can choose to be notified about every new message, just mentions or nothing. But you can't do anything about the notification sounds.

Comment: It's such a shame that this isn't a feature - it's be fantastic to have a 'Ching-ching' sound on the sales channel vs the regular sound on others